# What happens when a capacitor sees a change is its resistive load, under constant current?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, resistors, current-source, spike

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3HRq9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suppose the capacitor is fully charged at t < 0 s, so the current through C1 is 0 A, and the voltage across its terminals is I * R1. At t = 0 s we change the resistor R1 to R2 (step change) with R2 > R1. If we model the current through our resistor, we see a current spike. I solved the circuit mathematically, and made some spice simulations, but I can't fully grasp the idea behind this current (spike) behavior.

Comment: Might be easier to see if you convert the resistor and current source to a voltage source with series resistor using Thevenin.

Comment: @chris can you please add a specific question

Answer (score 1):

The voltage across an ideal capacitor can not change instantaneously, so if the resistor value changes instantaneously it must be true that the current through the resistor will also change instantaneously.

In other words, at the instant when the resistance changes the current will also change to keep the voltage constant. The circuit will eventually reach a steady state again, where the voltage is equal to the current times the new resistor value but there will be a "spike" in the resistor current at the **instant** when its value changes.

Comment: "it must be true that the current through the resistor will also change instantaneously." Why? The voltage across the capacitor can't change instantaneously, hence the voltage across the resistor can't, hence the current through the resistor can't. What is left to change instantaneously is the current through the capacitor.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Because the **value** of the resistor changed instantaneously. So if the voltage across the resistor is fixed, its current must change instantaneously. And yes, the capacitor current will also change but that was not what the OP asked...they asked about the **resistor current**.

Comment: @Elliot: Changes ready for your review.

Answer (score 0):

I1 will be a constant but there will be a sudden drop in current while the capacitor charges up. You won't get a voltage spike but the voltage will rise.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX39bY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. For simulation the value of the load resistance is doubled by disconnecting R2 after 20 ms.*

[image]
*Figure 2. Top, the voltage across C1. Bottom, the current through R3 (added to give a measuring point for the combined current through R1 and R2).*

The capacitor takes some of the current when the load voltage changes (lower trace). Without C1 the voltage (upper trace) would simply step from 5 to 10 V.

The current through R1 will be directly proportional to the voltage across it.

Comment: But that's not what the question asked. The question asked about the "current through our resistor", and assumed just one resistor with a step change in its value.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, CircuitLab doesn't allow for a step change in resistor value in its simulation. I used SW1 to switch out half the parallel resistance to go from 5k to 10k as an example of what was asked in the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: For your simulation, you should have plotted the total current through **both** resistors. That's what the OP asked about.

Comment: Yes, now we can see the spike in the current.